# Read and write data to excel using POI - It deletes my original data from excel after write new data

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am first reading data from excel and then write in same excel. It works fine first time. Just after data written , **It deletes my original data which was there from very beginning.**

code is given below :

```
 public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {


    //CODE TO REMOVE UNNECESSARY WARNING
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger");


    //CALL FIREFOX DRIVER TO OPEN IT
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=VQiAVOeCFavM8gf59IHACg&gws_rd=ssl#q=software+testing");
    java.util.List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("h3"));
    int sizecount = links.size(); 
    System.out.println(sizecount);

        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("D:\\sel.xls");
        int count=0;

        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(input);
        HSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("sheet1");
        HSSFRow row = sh.getRow(count);
        String data = row.getCell(0).toString();
        System.out.println(data);

        FileOutputStream webdata = new FileOutputStream ("D:\\sel.xls");

    int inc = 1;
    for(int i=1;i<=links.size()-1;i++)
    {


        HSSFRow row1 = sh.createRow(count);
        row1.createCell(inc).setCellValue(links.get(i).getText());
        count++;


    }
         wb.write(webdata);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are updating it, you should also update the count variable with the last line of the excel

```
 int inc = 1;
 count = sh.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
```

and do the rest...

Comment: Where I should this? because I already set count = 0; also count is working fine as per my code. new data is written in  one by one row.so that is not issue. I just want to keep my original data safe in excel when write new data.

Comment: @Helping Hands yes, if you are writing for the first time, but after that you already have some lines, so you should write after the last row... or not? and you should do this after setting the inc to 1...

Comment: which data type I need to set for count variable. Also I have already used count so need to create new variable called count1.

Comment: @Helping Hands no, you can use it, the idea is to continue writing in Excel after the last already written line... but if you prefer a new variable, then you can write int count1 = sh.getRows(); before the for loop and in the for loop: HSSFRow row1 = sh.createRow(count);

Comment: I am not auto getting when do int count1 = sh.  - It does not giving me .getRows method there. If I put by write then it does not  allow.

Comment: Sorry, that's for jexcelapi, you should use:  sh.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() (I edit my answer)

Comment: Yeah your given solution works little bit for me. Using that physical row method , it starts to write after last filled row. But what if I want to get last filled col. and want to start from 2nd column.?

Answer (score 1):

you are facing the issue because the index of excel sheets are same when you are writing.
First you should check wheater the cell is empty or not then you should write.
Or you can first do getrows() or getcolumn() it will give you the size of the rows and columns.
once you have the size you can write your data after the that row size and column.

Comment: But I am starting to write data from 2nd col and 1st cell. then why its creating issue?

Comment: because it will always start from 2nd col and 1st cell, you should not mention index explicitly, take index at run time

Comment: But when I read data , I have not used any loop. then how can I get runtime index?